# handle multiple entries at same time in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table of Auction where multiple users bid for an auction

```
ID |  BidderID |  AuctionID |  HighestBidPrice
------------------------------------------------
1  |  1        |  35        |  100
2  |  2        |  35        |  200
3  |  3        |  35        |  200
4  |  2        |  35        |  300
5  |  3        |  35        |  300
```

when 2 users make a bid at a same time both the bids become inserted into the table. I am trying to write a code to handle such type of deadlock condition for a particular AuctionID. There should not be even user able to insert less  price then last HighestBidPrice.

I check the condition in table by query like

```
$last_bid = $this->db->query("select * from Auction as A where A.AuctionID = 35 order by ID desc limit 1")->result_array();
```

first i get the last Highest bid price then check

```
if($last_bid){
        if(isset($last_bid[0]['HighestBidPrice']) && $last_bid[0]['HighestBidPrice']!=""){
            if($last_bid[0]['HighestBidPrice'] === $_POST['HighestBidPrice']){
                echo "The Bid with this price already made.";
            }
            if($last_bid[0]['HighestBidPrice'] >= $_POST['HighestBidPrice']){
                echo "The Bid price is less then Highest Bid Price.";
            }
        }
    }
```

Even than if multiple users simultaniously insert a bid both are able to make a bid.

Are the **Transactions** able to solve this problem?

Comment: I think instead of `transaction`, you have to `lock` and `unlock` the table at the time of insertion. Refer here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-table-locking/

Comment: if i lock the table what will be the result of other bids made by users at a same time?

Comment: In that case the second or subsequent request will wait until the first request completed and unlock the table.

Comment: Is it necessory to unloak the table just after a read. Can i lock the table for read then lock the table for write and at last unlock both?

Comment: @HarshwardhanSharma, try my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following way:

```
insert into auction (BidderID, AuctionID, HighestBidPrice)
select 10, 20, 500
where (SELECT max(HighestBidPrice) FROM auction WHERE AuctionID = 20) < 500;
```

This will insert a new auction only when the maximum bid rate for that particular auctionID less than 500;

Comment: this code inserted the bid but when multiple users make a bid simultaniously both bids inserted. And same HighestBidPrice inserted.

Comment: How are you creating the simultaneous bidding situation to test?

Comment: I have a button to make a bid on form. When 2 users simultaneous click he button BidIncrementPrice become add on HighestBidPrice and the new price becode the next bid of user.

Comment: So you are hitting the button from two computer at the same time?

Comment: yes i hit the button from different computers. This is the only way i can check multiple entries at a time.